# Be told - does it mean 'heed the advice'?

Tags: phrase-usage

From [Bucket Nut](https://books.google.com/books?id=cWj-mb-oQR0C) by Liza Cody:

> None of your tricks now, Eva,' he said. 'You play this one by the book. If you fuck up on this one I'll see you never work again in this business.'
>
> I looked at him, and behind me Ramses started growling.
>
> He said, 'Look Eva, do me a favour. Be told.'

Does it mean, 'Take what I'm saying seriously'? If so, is that standard usage?

Comment: Yes, 'Do as you're told!' Probably becoming archaic now, but once common in some parts of Britain.

Comment: I've never heard exactly this phrasing before, but I would take it to mean, from the context, "Accept the instructions as given; allow yourself to be told what to do" -- as opposed to thinking things through for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This usage would appear to be of the jocose kind in which an expression more familiar and accepted in the negative is arbitrarily converted to the positive by the speaker. The negative expression in this case is [“I won’t be told”](https://books.google.com/books?id=fIppxoagxRcC&pg=PA330&lpg=PA330&dq=%22I%20won%27t%20be%20told%22%20phrase&source=bl&ots=M4IMNsYBWw&sig=wvPXGiAq_IH94GBtlliqwV6Ldc8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtjfGstLjUAhUr7IMKHQfsDlkQ6AEIUDAK#v=onepage&q=%22I%20won%27t%20be%20told%22%20phrase&f=false)—as seen and discussed in the linked page of Lambotte’s *Aspects of Modern English Usage.* The joke in turning it positive is akin to that of removing the negating prefixes from *unkempt, disgruntled,* and *uncouth.*

So, yes, it does mean *heed the advice.*

Comment: Also, from your explanation, it seems that it's not standard usage (like something a dictionary would list).

Comment: I first heard the expression 'Be told!' over 50 years ago. It was common in the NW (at least) of England, often meaning 'Do as you're told!' / I can see  no 'turning the negative positive' here.

Answer (score 0):

Peeking at a synonyms page,  I'd go with "take possession" as in the sense of "receive this."  The intent is clear: he wants Eva to take his directions as seriously as possible and not to stray.